# Making read_only fields while Updating , but not in CREATE Method in ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Am new in python and I want to make an API in Django, one of the challenges am facing, am trying to make an UPDATE endpoint and a CREATE endpoint work.

When I neglect some of the required fields during UPDATING it works, but for the CREATE method doesn't,  it brings this error message :

```
IntegrityError at /api/articles/comment/4/replies/ null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (2018-09-20 04:24:36.225977+00, 89, English is better, null, null)
```

When I remove read_only in the serializers, the problem goes to the UPDATE endpoint as below in **postman**:

```
{
    "comment": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "author": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

The following is my code snippet:

**My Serializer in `serializers.py`**

```
class RepliesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Replies
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('comment', 'author',)
```

**The views in `views.py`.**

```
class RepliesView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Replies.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Replies.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def post(self, request, commentID):

        content = request.data
        author = request.user.id

        content['author'] = author
        content['comment'] = commentID
        # print('--> ', author)
        # print('content ---> ',content)
        serializer = RepliesSerializer(data=content)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self,request, commentID):
        instance = Replies.objects.all()
        serializer = RepliesSerializer(instance, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def delete(self, request, Id, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(Id)
        snippet.delete()
        return Response({"message" : "Reply Deleted Successfully."}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


    def put(self, request, Id):

        content = self.get_object(Id)
        serializer = RepliesSerializer(content, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**The model class in `model.py`**

```
"""
class to declare an article
model. To be used for all articles
"""

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from authors.apps.articles.utils import generate_slug
from authors.apps.authentication.models import User


# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
class Article(models.Model):
    """
    A model for an article
    """
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False,
                             error_messages={"required": "Write a short title for your article."})

    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False,
                                   error_messages={"required": "A description of your post is required."})

    body = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False,
                            error_messages={"required": "You cannot submit an article without body."})

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now=False, default=timezone.now)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now=False, default=timezone.now)

    favorited = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    favorites_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    photo_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        """
        :return: string
        """
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        override default save() to generate slug
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        """
        self.slug = generate_slug(Article, self)

        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'created_at'
        ordering = ['-created_at', 'author']


class Comments(models.Model):

    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    body = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, error_messages={"required": "You cannot submit without a comment."})

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now=False, default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        :return: string
        """
        return self.body

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'created_at'
        ordering = ['-created_at']


class Replies(models.Model):

    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comments, related_name='replies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='replies',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False,
                            error_messages={"required": "You cannot submit without a reply."})

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now=False, default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        :return: string
        """
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'created_at'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

***How can i make the logic which targets for both UPDATING and CREATING to avoid that error.***

Answer (score 1):

Making fields read_only not gonna solve your problem. Even if you make it as read_only by default model can't store blank value in database. If you not creating author and comment at the time of creating object then modify your model in such a way that it allows blank and null value.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: This one works, but the problem is, insert null values on author and comment, which cannot make a reference.

Comment: If you have a valid author or comment entry in that table you can specify it at the time of insertion. If you create a new article, there may be no comments yet. So storing blank means there is no related object.

Comment: I get your point, but my case all the **Replies** am making  do have **Comments**. I pass the **Id** of comments in the URL to reference it , after i post the reply.

Comment: So how can i make that clear, becaude when i look on my models , i see everything is fine , would mind , helping me out on that.

Comment: The thing is , when i remove the read_only on the fields in the serializers, the **comment** and **author** be availbale , but when i add them the ***comment_id*** and ***author_id*** becomes null

Comment: As i said earlier your problem is not in serializer. When you make author and comment read only field and call serializer to store data those fields won't consider by serializer for create or save   operation. Serializer only consider these fields for a get operation. But at your model level those fields can't be null.

Comment: You are using request.user.id. If you are not authenticated it returns Abstract User object. So check that one too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180419/discussion-between-lutaaya-huzaifah-idris-and-a-k-v).